# Windows 10 on Lenovo T480 - can CPU be told to be so slow that fans never start?

Tags: windows-10, bios, fan, power-management, lenovo-laptop

I have been assigned a Lenovo T480 machine with Windows 10.  Unfortunately something (probably the anti-virus software which has plenty to do as I do Java development) uses so much CPU that the fans speed up occasionally.

This is quite annoying and the CPU is powerful enough that I don't *need* full speed.

Is there a setting in Windows 10 or the BIOS that tells the CPU to throttle enough down that the fans will not kick in?

Comment: If the fan did not need to increase the speed, then the fan speed would remain at a lower RPM, the fact the fan RPM is increases indicates your system requires it.  However, what you describe, requires your Administrator to make the modifications.  This cannot be done with a non-Administrator account, nor should you be making changes like this, without permission from your Administrator.  You might see some benefit from adding folder exclusions to your AV though.  Your CPU is already throttling itself down, and increases the speed of the fan, in order to keep the thermals under control

Comment: In most cases, Intel does not provide a way to configure the temperature in which a CPU will be throttled back.  However, if that setting does exist, it would be in the firmware settings.  Which again, requires your IT Administrator, to configure.

Comment: @Ramhound I have firmware access and there is no such direct setting in the BIOS.

Comment: If there is no setting then what you want isn't possible with the hardware you have.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a possibility: in Windows 10, you can specify the maximum cpu usage in the Energyoptions. If you set this value to 50% or 70%, the fan will not go an anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little research and it looks like the thermals are really bad on this laptop. There are a lot of people complaining about the same issues and the reason why your fans are picking up is because the thermals are high. Here is a forum of people talking about similar issues, one person replaced the thermal paste and got better thermals. Wouldn't be a bad idea to try new thermal paste or get your IT department to do it, if you have one.

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-T400-T500-and-newer-T/T480-throttling-and-high-CPU-temps/td-p/4036815

Edit: If it is the thermals in why the fan is picking up, you do not want to lower or turn off the fans, even though there is software you can download to do this with.

Comment: Thank you.  I would be fine with having the CPU do less work (and therefore not be so hot) instead.  Apparently this is something nobody else ever wants to do :)

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I wouldn't be surprised if your CPU isn't do much work, it is most likely throttling because of the temperatures.

Comment: This is a rather poor answer to the question "Is there a setting in Windows 10 or the BIOS that tells the CPU to throttle down?"